# SQL server how to do string comparison with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: the entry table (one nvarchar column called entry) and the disease table (one nvarchar column called disease).

I would like to produce another table that has all the entry-disease combos where entry.entry is contained completely in disease.disease. However, I want all entries that do not have a disease that is completely contained inside of them to still appear in the results table as {entry, blank}.

I know it should probably be something like:

select entry disease from
entry, disease
where ...

not really sure how to write this, thanks in advance

Ok, I figured out this much:

```
select entry.entry, disease.disease
into new_table
from entry, disease
where CHARINDEX(entry, disease) > 0
```

how do I include the entries that have no match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) in this case.
It will show all entries and provide `null` value for the column `disease.disease` if an entry is not contained in any cell of `disease.disease`.

```
SELECT entry.entry, disease.disease
FROM entry LEFT JOIN disease
    ON CHARINDEX(entry.entry, disease.disease) > 0
```

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. Just to clarify. Using this, if I have an entry A within which a disease b and disease c both exist then I will get two rows {a, b}, {a, c} right?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use LIKE keyword. Please see the example below:

```
create table #t (st varchar(20))
insert into #t values ('johnalexmichael'), ('johnmichael'),('alex'),('michael')
create table #t2 (st varchar(20))
insert into #t2 values ('alex'),('john')

SELECT t.st, t2.st
FROM #t t 
LEFT JOIN #t2 t2 on t.st like '%'+t2.st+'%'
```